# Equals Method not working in string[]

Tags: java, equals

```
public String modUsernames[] = {"Test", "Test2"};
public String adminUsernames[] = {"Mod Jack", "Mod Demon"};

if (username.equals(modUsernames)) {
    rights = 1;
}
if (username.equals(adminUsernames)) {
    rights = 2;
}
```

How come this isn't working, and what would I do to get it working?

Comment: you simply need to learn code concept of java . BTW you could more understand by this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus

Answer (score 3):

```
(username.equals(modUsernames))
```

You **should not** compare String to Array and if username is an array than you can't check whether both are eqaul like this.

Use `Arrays.equals(ar1,ar2)` for this.

Or use array index and use loop to check one by one.

```
username.equals(modUsernames[0])
```

Or you can use `Arrays.toString()` and use `contains` method

```
Arrays.toString(modUsernames).contains(username);
```

Comment: You can - it's just always `false` :-)

Comment: @Sebastian  Yes I agree because equals takes `Object` as an argument and that's why it allows this comparison.Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `username` is a `String`: The variable `modUsernames` is an array of `String`s, it's not a single `String`. You have to compare the `String` `username` with one elemenet of that array:

```
if (username.equals(modUsernames[0]))
```

for example.

**Note:** The way you access to an element of an array is using an *index*:

```
someArray[index]
```

Index in most programming languages start in `0`. So, if the length of the array is 2 (i.e. it has two elements), you can *only* use the index `0` and `1`.

Comment: I don't really understand, I tried that and it still isn't working. :/

Comment: What's `username`? What is its value? (you can see this using `System.out.println`)

Comment: Username is `private transient String username;`

Comment: And what's its content?

Answer (score 2):

As stated by others you cannot compare a `String` to an `String[]`, what you can do is to check whether the `String` is contained in the `String[]`, e.g.:

```
if (Arrays.asList(modUsernames).contains(username)){
   rights = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here what is your intention to compare . If it is to compare `arrays` then you may go with `Arrays.equal(arr1,arr2)`. or if your intention to compare the index vales then you can go `string.equals(str2)`;